# Build output voltage graph as a result of the integration on an ideal integrator

Tags: operational-amplifier, homework, graph

Picture related is an original task(in Ukrainian):

[image]

Translation of the task 1(till «Задача 2»):

Build the graphic result of the integration on an ideal integrator if **R=40 kOmh**, **C=20 uF** and the input signal is show in the graph( where **U1=1 V, U2=2 V, t_i=i*delta t, delta t= 2 seconds**). Maximum output voltage of the operational amplifier equals +-14 V

U_вх   -   U_input

U_вих -   U_output

**Me, trying to solve it:**

I have a graph how does input voltage change. I need to find how does output voltage change.

Voltage is the potential difference, so to find voltage in out, I simply need to find the potential of the out node.

The first step is to find the potential of the node after R. Then I have to find how does potential changes after capacitor, and what is the potential of the amplifiers out. The result will be potential after capacitor at some time + potential in the amplifier out.

I don’t know what to do with capacitor when I have non-harmonique signal. I know that capacitor charge time is 3RC and the current through it falls exponentially.

I remember that in last lectures professor explained that we should make an equations for each intervals on the graph, like y=ax+b for output signal. This equations comes from definite integral of what I do not remember...

Well, I found this:

[image]

I think I should put instead y U_out, and instead x U_in (exactly voltage in amplifier, not just input voltage ). Hmmm, maybe it is the whole solution? I just integrate from t0 t1, got the line equation for this interval, integrate from t1 to t2 and the same

Can you figure me?

Comment: So, how **can** we help you? I'm sure you've got *some* approach, but you're stuck somewhere. What's your own, specific question about the assignment.

Comment: @MarcusMüller added some thoughts

Comment: awesome! Much better :)